# Sass: @Extend Sibling (3rd level) without previous Sibling (2nd) name

Tags: css, sass

Currently, I'm looking for the best way go about Sass.. so here is the problem and what structure I'm looking for is:

```
.block-color-default, .block-color-default--inner{
       ...........
}
.block-color-default--inner{
      .........
}
```

But a bad result I got from my code is:

```
.block-color-default, .block-color .block-color-default--inner{
       ...........
}
.block-color-default--inner{
      ......... << -- (cannot override the css above)
}
```

Here is my code:

```
.block{

    &-color{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display:block;
    background-color: #ccc;

          &-default, %third{
             width:100px;
             height:50px;
             background-color:#fff;

             &--inner{
                @extend %third;
                background-color: #000;
             }

          }
    }
}
```

What's the best way to go about this? I do not want to use !important.
Thank you very much for advices.

Cheers,

Comment: You can create a mixin and include it in default and default--inner level. [Something like this](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/OPvaNZ)

Comment: Thank you @anpsmn, I guess I have to go for the mixin :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@at-root` directive to remove all parents in your compiled CSS:

```
.block{

    &-color{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    display:block;
    background-color: #ccc;

          @at-root &-default, %third{
             width:100px;
             height:50px;
             background-color:#fff;

             &--inner{
                @extend %third;
                background-color: #000;
             }

          }
    }
}
```

Generated CSS:

```
.block-color { width: 100%; height: 500px; display: block; background-color: #ccc; }
.block-color-default, .block-color-default--inner { width: 100px; height: 50px; background-color: #fff; }
.block-color-default--inner { background-color: #000; }
```

[Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root)

Comment: Thank you @zessx! I think this is what I've been looking for :)

Comment: You're welcome. Consider to upvote and/or mark this answer as accepted to close this question if you think your problem was solved.